# Will WebAnimations support vector shape transformations

Tags: svg, vector, shapes, smil, web-animations

We have been using SVG path animations (SMIL), since CSS is very limited and have now heard that SMIL will soon vanish from all browsers.
Does anyone know whether WebAnimations will support vector shape animations and not just classic positions/rotation/scale animations?

Comment: They will eventually, it's not yet clear how though as the specifications are still being written. Firefox has no plans to remove SMIL currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Animations API can animate any element or property that CSS animations or transitions can.